# Django - Function continuing to execute despite subfunction 404

Tags: python, django, exception

When #A runs

```
def add_particle_to_atom(particle_uid, atom_uid):

  node_data = find_node_by_uid(particle_uid) #A
  particle = node_data['queryset'] #B
```

It triggers this function that I thought would cause an exception in the REPL.

```
def find_node_by_uid(node_uid):
  # ...
  try:
    # thing will fail because i'm giving it garbage for a uid
  except: 
    print("|--- ERROR: there is no particle with that uid.")
    return HttpResponseNotFound("404")
```

But the console give an error that is associated with #B.

```
>>> add_particle_to_atom('wefjhwljefh',a)
|--- CHECK: if particle with uid 'wefjhwljefh' exists.
|--- ERROR: there is no particle with that uid.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/layne/Desktop/AlchDB/alchemy/views.py", line 258, in add_particle_to_atom
    particle = node_data['queryset']
  File "/Users/layne/Desktop/venv_alchdb/alchdb/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 145, in __getitem__
    return self._headers[header.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'queryset'
```

Why does it do this when I have told the sub-function to 404? And I know it is failing because the `print` is running. I don't want to exit because I still want the REPL usable.

UPDATE: If I put #A's return before the print, it skips the print and goes straight back to executing the main function.

Comment: When you do this `node_data = find_node_by_uid(particle_uid)` you're just setting `node_data` to have whatever that function returns. If you want your view flow to be interrupted from the "subfunction" you need to raise an exception

Comment: I went back to raising an exception. I guess if debug is set to false... then I wouldn't be blasting out tracebacks anyways